# How to generate URL with repeated query parameters in `webapp2.uri_for`

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, webapp2

I want to generate an uri like this: `/some/path?a=123&a=456` (note that parameter `a` is repeated twice).

Tried this: `webapp2.uri_for("handler-name", a=[123,456])` and gave me this: `?a=%5B123%2C+345%5D` (which is the url-friendly form of the string: `"[123, 456]"`

Not much is said in the [docs](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.uri_for). [More](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Router.build).

How can I generate repeated parameters in a URI?